# Open all files in project with long lines in an editor

Tags: bash, emacs

I'd like to edit all text files under a certain directory that have one or more lines that are over a certain threshold in length. How can I do that?

To keep things simple, let's assume that all the text files in the directory and its subdirectories have the same file extension - let's say `.java`.

P.S. My editor of choice is emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on gniourf_gniourf's answer, here is a way that works within emacs, and allows you to jump directly to the overlong lines with `TAB` followed by `RET`:

```
M-x rgrep RET .\{116\} RET *.java RET [insert directory to scan here] RET
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want recursion into subdirectories, it's much simpler to do just this:

```
grep -lZ '.\{116\}' *.java | xargs -0 "${EDITOR:=emacs}"
```

If you need recursion into subdirectories, use the `globstar` option:

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -lZ '.\{116\}' **/*.java | xargs -0 "${EDITOR:=emacs}"
```

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal, after changing to the directory in question, type:

```
find -name '*.java' -exec awk -vORS=$'\\0' 'length > 116 {print FILENAME; nextfile}' {} +|xargs -0 ${EDITOR:=emacs}
```

This will open all the `.java` files that have lines longer than 116 characters in a new instance of emacs - unless your EDITOR environment variable is set to the name of some other text editor, in which case it will open them in that instead.